# No source code is available for type org.quartz.CronExpression; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Tags: java, maven, gwt, cron

My application is based on GWT.

I am trying to validate the cron expression using `org.quartz-scheduler.quartz-2.2.1.jar` to validate the cron expression.

But when I try to put a maven build I got below error.

```
[INFO] Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
[INFO]    [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/rd/target/classes/org/drools/guvnor/client/asseteditor/drools/CalendarEditor.java'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 843: No source code is available for type org.quartz.CronExpression; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

My pom.xml configuration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <classifier>sources</classifier>
</dependency>
```

I have included the sources for `quartz-2.2.1.jar` also but I still got the above exception.
So suggest some solutions to resolve the above issue.

But in the same GWT application hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA-source and hibernate-core-3.3.2.jar is used with the same configuration it got builded successfully .

Comment: You are trying to use code, which is not inside a GWT module or you did forget to inherit a module.

Comment: I am trying to use the code which is not inside the GWT module.

Comment: Then how i can use quartz-scheduler-2.2.1 jar in my GWT application

Comment: If there is no GWT implementation, you can not!

Comment: No El Hoss , the java file called Calendareditor .java is actually present in the client side of gwt application so i am trying to use quartz jar in that . It works fine eclipse when i imported the jar via java-build path but during maven build it throws an error . This is the problem

Comment: Were you able to run your GWT app with SuperDevMode or DevMode? I think not.

Comment: In DevMode but i cannot able to debug the code through eclipse.

Comment: As long as the code is not executed in DevMode, it will work. Try to compile your project with the Elcipse Plugin. You will get the same error message. @Ajax gave already the answer why (and regarding the content that's the intention of my first answer.)

Answer (score 1):

You have added `CronExpression.java` class reference in your client side class `CalendarEditor.java`. `CronExpression.java` does not belongs to any known GWT module. To clear doubts about adding external jar in GWT aplication this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243290/how-to-include-a-external-jar-in-a-gwt-google-web-toolkit-project) will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

GWT compiles Java into Javascript, and knows how to do that only for certain classes, not all of them. You can't just pick up any Java class off the net, and expect it to work.

So you can either find an alternative class that GWT knows about, or you can do it with Javascript.

Comment: I tried using an alternative for quartz for GWT pentaho-gwt-widgets-5.0.1.jar. And i included the source file also . but i am still getting the same error  "No source code is available for type org.pentaho.gwt.widgets.client.i18n.WidgetsLocalizedMessages; did you forget to inherit a required module?"